# how to make a for loop in expect, run trough all lines in a file

Tags: expect

im tring to make a sftp login script using expect, and i want to have a file with the ip address for each remote.host that i want to connect to.
how do i make a for function in expect to go trough every line in the ip adress file and make its variable assume the string in each line.
The code i currently have is

````
set filehandle [open /home/logs r]
while {[gets $filehandle line] != -1} {
spawn sftp user@$filehandle
sleep 1
expect "*password:" [send "password/r"]
sleep1
expect "*" [send "get /home/holder/r"]
sleep 1
expect "*" [send "bye/r"]}


i get the following response
```spawn sftp user@server
user@server´s password: spawn sftp user@server
user@server´s password: user@hostname:/home/user
````

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: You are sending `/r` instead of `\r`. Also, while you're developing your, add `exp_internal 1` near the top of the code.

Comment: changing it to \ just makes it print to new lines the error still persists, its like it only runs the spawn command and then keeps repeating it as an answer to itself its so wierd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up shell and expect: `for ...; do ...; done` is shell syntax

You want:

```
set filehandle [open /home/logs r]
while {[gets $filehandle line] != -1} {
    spawn sftp user@$line
    # ...
}
close $filehandle
```

Expect is an extension of the Tcl language. You might want to look at the Tcl tutorial: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html

Comment: could you explain to me the syntax of the while in your code im having a hard time understanding it

Comment: That's how you read file one line at a time. See this chapter from the Tcl tutorial: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl24.html

Comment: ok so im getting a new error and its realy wierd , ive updated the description.